# AWS ECS task can't access outbound

Tags: amazon-ecs

I created docker image that based on ubuntu:18.04

Maybe I think ECS task cannot access to outbound.

When I execute `apt-get update`, it throw errors.

```
root@ip-172-31-14-71:~# apt-get install -y wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpsl5 publicsuffix
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpsl5 publicsuffix wget
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 455 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1320 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpsl5 amd64 0.19.1-5build1
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 publicsuffix all 20180223.1310-1
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 wget amd64 1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 wget amd64 1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpsl/libpsl5_0.19.1-5build1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/publicsuffix/publicsuffix_20180223.1310-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wget/wget_1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@ip-172-31-14-71:~# apt-get install -y wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpsl5 publicsuffix
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpsl5 publicsuffix wget
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 455 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1320 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpsl5 amd64 0.19.1-5build1
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 publicsuffix all 20180223.1310-1
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 wget amd64 1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 wget amd64 1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpsl/libpsl5_0.19.1-5build1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/publicsuffix/publicsuffix_20180223.1310-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wget/wget_1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

`wget` to google.com also failed.

I do not configure any firewalls or related about that.

Is there any configuration for ECS task?

Comment: This wouldn't be at the task level, unless you're explicitly setting the network mode to none. Are you 100% sure the EC2 host is in a subnet with outbound access, or that you haven't set a security group blocking/allowing outbound traffic?

Comment: @Hide I have a similar issue where creating an ECS cluster, then creating a service with tasks through the wizard, by default the containers are not able to make outbound requests. I have found that if I manually start the image, it somehow binds with my default VPC instead and is able to make outbound requests.